# how to bind a view and partial view that contain form and i need to access in the main view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using web API and asp.net mvc. I have a model called tax and the main view use tax model to retrieve tax list using web API. I need to load partial view into that main view and partial view contains a form that opens in the main view using a popup dialog box model. I created ViewModel called taxviewmodel and it contains tax and list form of tax as properties. When I'm debugging there no error but no record was added into the database

Comment: Hi, please add related code sections to your question, and explain more about the situation (for example, you don't mention anything about the database before the last phrase) and finally consider [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)